# Java ParseInt Error

Tags: java

I am getting an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:542)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at Maze.<init>(Maze.java:24)
    at Assignment1.main(Assignment1.java:13)
```

I have two classes, Maze and Assignment1:

`import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;

```
public class Maze
{
  private Vertex[] rooms;
  private String a = "";

  public Maze(String filename)
  {  

      BufferedReader readFile = null;
      String line, roomname;
      int roomXcoord, roomYcoord, room1 = 0, room2 = 0;
 try{   
         readFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Parth\\Documents\\try.maze"));
         line = readFile.readLine(); //next line

         while (line != null) {
          System.out.println(line);
          line = readFile.readLine();    
         } //end first - while

          int temp = Integer.parseInt(line);
          rooms = new Vertex[temp];
          for(int i=0; i <rooms.length; i++)
          {
              StringTokenizer strk = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");
              roomname = strk.nextToken();
              roomXcoord = Integer.parseInt(strk.nextToken());
              roomYcoord = Integer.parseInt(strk.nextToken());
              rooms[i] = new Vertex(roomname, roomXcoord, roomYcoord);  
          }
          line = readFile.readLine();

          while (room1 != -1 && room2 != -1)
          {   line=readFile.readLine();
            StringTokenizer strk =new StringTokenizer(line," ");
            room1=Integer.parseInt(strk.nextToken());
            room2=Integer.parseInt(strk.nextToken());
          }
 }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public Vertex[] getRooms()
  {

    return rooms;  
  }

  public String toString()
  {   
      for (int i=0; i<rooms.length; i++){
      a =  rooms[i].getName() + " " + rooms[i].getXCoord() + " " + rooms[i].getYCoord() +"\n";
      }
    return a;
}//end toString

}//end Maze`



    import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

/**
 * 
 * 
 *
 */
public class Assignment1 {

 public static void main(String[] args){
  Maze newMaze = new Maze(null);
  System.out.println(newMaze.toString());  
 }
}
```

I understand null is the error, but i am still able to see my input file which is:

[image: Sample Input]

The error appears on Maze class on line 24: `int temp = Integer.parseInt(line);`
and in the assignment1 class on line 13:  `Maze newMaze = new Maze(null);`

How do i get rid of this error?

Comment: It would seem you're trying to parse a `null` value to `int`, you're going to have to debug your code to find out why

Comment: After this `while (line != null) {` `line` is now `null` so of course `Integer.parseInt(line);` will fail

Comment: I see in your simple input lines some character instead of numbers, you can use int.tryParse() to avoid throwing exception in this case

Comment: @user7790438 gives me a syntax error.

Comment: Sorry I meant to implement your own one like this:
boolean tryParseInt(String value) {  
     try {  
         Integer.parseInt(value);  
         return true;  
      } catch (NumberFormatException e) {  
         return false;  
      }  
}

Comment: That didn't workout but i was thinking of changing the loop instead of that one line. Thanks anyways @user7790438.

Comment: Your problem is that your first loop is consuming your entire file, so there's nothing left for the rest of the program to read.  Rethink what the exit condition should be for that first loop.

Answer (score -1):

```
while (line != null) {
   System.out.println(line);
   line = readFile.readLine();    
} //end first - while

// Here the line will be null
int temp = Integer.parseInt(line);
```